# How do i convert the google-ads tag into react code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-ads-script

I have some tags for google ads in following vanilla js format but I am not sure how to integrate in React, can anybody help with that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-3715562101512710";
/* Clapingo_728x90 */
google_ad_slot = "JustBaat_Clapingo\/Clapingo_728x90";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by integrate?

Comment: convert it to react code basically

Comment: You don't need to convert it to react code, usually you need to paste that code in the html file where you have the  html `<head>` tag or you can check if https://github.com/alinemorelli/react-gtm work for you